# Convert a recursive jump point search implementation into an iterative implementation

Tags: python, a-star

So I've got this recursive function which I want to convert to an iterative version. How could I do this?

```py
def jump(grid: np.ndarray, current: Point, parent: Point, end: Point) -> Point | None:
    if not reachable(grid, *current):
        return None

    if current == end:
        return current

    dx, dy = current.x - parent.x, current.y - parent.y
    if dx != 0 and dy != 0:
        if jump(grid, Point(current.x + dx, current.y), current, end) or jump(
            grid, Point(current.x, current.y + dy), current, end
        ):
            return current
    elif dx != 0:
        if (
            not reachable(grid, current.x - dx, current.y - 1)
            and reachable(grid, current.x, current.y - 1)
        ) or (
            not reachable(grid, current.x - dx, current.y + 1)
            and reachable(grid, current.x, current.y + 1)
        ):
            return current
    else:
        if (
            not reachable(grid, current.x - 1, current.y - dy)
            and reachable(grid, current.x - 1, current.y)
        ) or (
            not reachable(grid, current.x + 1, current.y - dy)
            and reachable(grid, current.x + 1, current.y)
        ):
            return current

    if reachable(grid, current.x + dx, current.y) and reachable(
        grid, current.x, current.y + dy
    ):
        return jump(grid, Point(current.x + dx, current.y + dy), current, end)
    else:
        return None
```

The `Point` class and the `reachable` function:

```py
OBSTACLE_ID = 1

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int


def reachable(grid: np.ndarray, x: int, y: int) -> bool:
    return (
        0 <= x < grid.shape[1]
        and 0 <= y < grid.shape[0]
        and grid[y][x] != OBSTACLE_ID
    )
```

The code to run jump point search:

```py
INTERCARDINAL_OFFSETS = (
    (-1, -1),
    (0, -1),
    (1, -1),
    (-1, 0),
    (1, 0),
    (-1, 1),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 1),
)

grid = [
    [10, 11, 4, 13, 14, -3, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 4, 29],
    [30, 31, 32, 33, 4, 35, 36, 37, 38, 4],
    [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 4, 48, 49],
    [50, 4, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 4, 58, 59],
    [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
    [70, 4, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
    [80, -2, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
    [90, 91, 92, 93, 4, 95, 4, 97, 98, 99],
    ]


def find_neighbours(
    current: Point, parent: Point | None
) -> Generator[Point, None, None]:
    if parent:
        dx, dy = (
            (current.x - parent.x) // max(abs(current.x - parent.x), 1),
            (current.y - parent.y) // max(abs(current.y - parent.y), 1),
        )

        if dx != 0 and dy != 0:
            x_mods = (dx, 0, dx)
            y_mods = (0, dy, dy)
        elif dx != 0:
            x_mods = (dx, dx, dx)
            y_mods = (0, 1, -1)
        else:
            x_mods = (0, 1, -1)
            y_mods = (dy, dy, dy)
        yield from (
            Point(current.x + x_mod, current.y + y_mod)
            for x_mod, y_mod in zip(x_mods, y_mods)
        )
    else:
        yield from (
            Point(current.x + dx, current.y + dy) for dx, dy in INTERCARDINAL_OFFSETS
        )

def calculate_astar_path(grid: np.ndarray, start: Point, end: Point) -> list[Point]:
    heap: list[tuple[int, Point, Point | None]] = [(0, start, None)]
    came_from: dict[Point, Point] = {start: start}
    distances: dict[Point, int] = {start: 0}

    while heap:
        _, current, parent = heappop(heap)

        if current == end:
            result = []
            while True:
                result.append(current)

                if came_from[current] != current:
                    current = came_from[current]
                else:
                    break
            return result

        for neighbour in find_neighbours(current, parent):
            jump_point = jump(grid, neighbour, current, end)
            if jump_point is not None and jump_point not in came_from:
                came_from[jump_point] = current
                distances[jump_point] = distances[came_from[jump_point]] + 1
                f_cost = distances[jump_point] + max(
                    abs(neighbour.x - current.x), abs(neighbour.y - current.y)
                )
                heappush(heap, (f_cost, jump_point, current))

    return []


res = calculate_astar_path(np.array(grid), Point(1, 7), Point(0, 5))
```

Comment: What does your code do? What have you tried? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's always possible to replace recursion with iteration.  If the recursion wasn't "needed" in the first place, then it's very easy.  But if the recursion was "needed", by which I mean if it made use of call stack to save needed state, then you need to identify the needed state and use your own stack to save/restore it at the points where you previously made a recursive call.

Comment: I've added the code which can be used to run the algorithm

Comment: I think this is something you're going to need to work out for yourself.  Maybe start with a simpler practice problem.  In the most general case, at a recursive call point, you would need to save the local variables of that function, and an indication of where the call was made from (so you know where to go when popping the stack and "returning" in the iterative version).